# Dynamic imports with webpack and angular, Cannot find some?

Tags: angular, webpack, dynamic-import

Im using angular 6 and webpack 4 in order to dynamically import a webpackchunk specifically "animation.gsap" from scrollmagic and "TimelineMax", "TweenMax", "TweenLite", etc. ALL THE TWEENS.

However it cannot find them despite the paths being correct, I go through and am able to find them as well as successfully dynamically importing ScrollMagic.

Am I missing something, anyone able to help guide me through to see if theres something im missing?

Here is my Webpack config:

```
config.mode = 'development';
  config.target = 'web';
  config.devtool = '';
  config.resolve = {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: ['node_modules', './node_modules/'],
    alias: {
      'TweenLite': 'gsap/src/minified/TweenLite.min.js',
      'TweenMax': 'gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js',
      'TimelineLite': 'gsap/src/minified/TimelineLite.min.js',
      'TimelineMax': 'gsap/src/minified/TimelineMax.min.js',
      'animation.gsap': 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js',
      'ScrollMagic': 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/ScrollMagic.min.js',
    }
  };
```

I've als tried 2 ways of importing :

```
const importSM = normalizeCommonJSImport(
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "ScrollMagic" */ 'ScrollMagic'),
);

const importGsap = normalizeCommonJSImport(
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "animation.gsap" */ 'animation.gsap'),
);
```

And:

```
   initAnimations(pJSONData) {
         import(/*webpackChunkName: "animation.gsap" */ "animation.gsap").then(({default: 
            animationGsap}) => {
           import(/*webpackChunkName: "TweenMax" */ "TweenMax").then(({default: TweenMax}) => {.
           import(/*webpackChunkName: "lottie" */ "lottie-web").then(({default: lottie}) => {
           import(/*webpackChunkName: "ScrollMagic" */ "ScrollMagic").then(({default: ScrollMagic})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using an import from the path and not just the chunkName.

```
   import(/*webpackChunkName: "TweenMax" */ "gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js").then(({default: TweenMax}) => {
```

For example